# Can LESS styles be applied to an Angular Dart component?

Tags: dart, less, angular-dart

Is there any possibility to add LESS styles to angular.dart component? It would be great if they would run in run-time, without compilation to CSS. I'm afraid it can be quite difficult due to Shadow DOM components' structure, what do you think?

This is what I'd like to reach in component file:

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'sample',
  templateUrl: 'sample/sample_component.html',
  cssUrl: 'sample/sample_component.less'
)
class SampleComponent {
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question -- No.  However, it's possible to achieve the desired effect with the right tooling.  I wrote the css for my components in less, which were auto-watched and compiled by my IDE of choice, WebStorm.

In your case, you would edit a `sample/sample_component.less` file, and upon saving it, it would compile to css.  Your component would reference the compiled `sample/sample_component.less`.  As I mentioned, WebStorm took care of watching the files for me, but there should be ways to accomplish this without the aid of an IDE.

Comment: Yes I know I can acheive it by watches from IDE or command-line. But I don't know what excaclty does `cssUrl` attribute, in generated HTML I can see only css file configs in shadowed component contents. Maybe some transformer could take that?

Comment: The cssUrl attribute, AFAIK, tells angular where to fetch the css for the component.  It would be possible (albeit not trivial) to create a transformer that would compile the files to css.  Angular does do template caching though, and I'm not sure if it caches the component's css, but that may thwart any attempt at using transformers for this purpose.